# How to build a query using NativeSearchQueryBuilder from List of QueryBuilder in Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have added a list of QueryBuilders if certain properties are matched. Now, I want to search using these list.

```java
    @Override
    public List<com.example.jobcandidatemanagement.documents.Job> searchJobs(String phrase, LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate, double offeredSalary, Availability availability) {

        List<QueryBuilder> searchQueries = new ArrayList<>();

        if (phrase != null) {
            QueryBuilder byPhrase = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(phrase, "position", "description");
            searchQueries.add(byPhrase);
        }

        if (startDate != null && endDate != null) {
            QueryBuilder byStartDate = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("startDate").gt(JsonData.of(startDate));
            QueryBuilder byEndDate = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("endDate").lt(JsonData.of(endDate));
            searchQueries.add(byStartDate);
            searchQueries.add(byEndDate);
        }

        if (offeredSalary >= 0) {
            QueryBuilder byOfferedSalary = QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("offeredSalary").lte(offeredSalary);
            searchQueries.add(byOfferedSalary);
        }

        if (availability != null) {
            QueryBuilder byAvailability = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("availability", availability);
            searchQueries.add(byAvailability);
        }

    }
```

I want to create a query using these all above queryBuilder. Something like this :

```java
Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(byPhrase)
                                            .withQuery(byStartDate)
                                            .withQuery(byEndDate)
                                            .withQuery(byOfferedSalary)
                                            .withQuery(byAvailability)
                                            .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your method to add every new `QueryBuilder` not in a `List`, but in a [`BoolQueryBuilder`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/latest/org.elasticsearch.server/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoolQueryBuilder.html) by using its [`must(QueryBuilder queryBuilder)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/latest/org.elasticsearch.server/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoolQueryBuilder.html#must(org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder)) method:

```java
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

if (phrase != null) {
    QueryBuilder byPhrase = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(phrase, "position", "description");
    boolQueryBuilder.must(byPhrase);
}
// adding other builders
```

`BoolQueryBuilder` also implements `QueryBuilder` interface, so then you can do this:

```java
Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(boolQueryBuilder).build();
```

Note, that `must()` method means that passed query must appear in the matching documents and **will** *contribute to scoring*. If you don't want to affect scoring, try [`filter(QueryBuilder queryBuilder)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/latest/org.elasticsearch.server/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoolQueryBuilder.html#filter(org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder)), which does the same, but passed query **will not** *contribute to scoring*.